# entry_points in setup.py and environment variables

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have a problem with a script generated with `entry_points` of setuptools (setup.py). It breaks on import: `from pkg_resources import load_entry_point`.

```py
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import plistlib
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/plistlib.py", line 65, in <module>
    from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyexpat import *
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt
```

I found that it's because in the environment where my script runs, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set (to Oracle installation directory). My script doesn't use it, but it's just part of a set of scripts. It's a legacy system, so modifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is impossible.

Is there a way to still use `entry_points` or in this case I have to use the "good old" `scripts`?

Cheers:)

Comment: I assume, that contrarily to what you think  your script uses at least one .so from that directory.

you could use `strace` to check what files are opened. 

`strace` is very verbose. just grep for the open commands to the oracle installation dir.

If you have that information you could add it to your question

Comment: Would it be an option to edit the generated tar file and to edit the entry point such, that it deletes `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  with `import os ; del os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]`

Even if it's not an option you could try it out to see whether it would have a positive impact

Comment: @gelonida Not my script - it's the `load_entry_point`

Comment: sorry I expressed my self badly:
Would it be possible to edit the file that calls load_entry_point.
At least for finding out if it would really resolve the issue?

Comment: in the end, I used the good old `scripts` in `setup.py`